# Why is R# reddifying bits of my code?

Tags: asp.net-web-api, resharper, resharper-8.0, code-inspection

When I run ReSharper > Inspect > Code Issues in Solution in my client app (in VS 2008), I get the expected "Inspection Results" dialog.

However, when I run ReSharper > Inspect > Code Issues in Solution on my Web API app (in VS 2013),not only does it not show the expected "Inspection Results" dialog, but it reddifies some qualifiers:

[image]

The project compiles just fine.

Is this reddification of portions of my code some sort of sick joke perpetrated by Chinese hackers? More importantly (assuming that's just normal paranoia), how can I get the dialog to display, showing me any "issues" the R# code inspector found?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this situation, the best thing to do is to clear ReSharper's caches and see if that fixes things. Go to ReSharper -> Options -> General -> Clear caches, then close and reopen the solution. Hopefully, everything should be recognised just fine.

Comment: Okay, I'll try that; maybe inspecting the two solutions at the same time caused the problem.